# Search Using PHP displays all Database Data

Tags: php, database, search

I am trying to search some data from a database. The search works fine, however if I click on search without entering anything into the form, it displays all the data on the database. Anyway I can fix this?

This is my php code.

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,"AnimalTracker1");

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysqli_error($link));
  }
$searchKeyword = $_POST['find']; // Sanitize this value first !!
   $sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations WHERE `Animal_Type` LIKE '%$searchKeyword%' ");



if ($sql == FALSE)
{
  die($sql." Error on query: ".mysqli_error($link)); 
 }

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo  $result ['Animal_Type'];
echo "<br>";
echo $result ['Latitude'];
echo "<br> ";
echo $result ['Longitude'];
echo " <br>";
echo $result ['Seen'];
echo " <br> ";
echo $result ['Time'];
echo "<br> ";
echo "<br> ";
}
//}
?>
```

Comment: u can check whether $searchKeyword is empty or not before executing your query. do that client side/server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure $searchKeyword has a (valid) value

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,"AnimalTracker1");

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysqli_error($link));
  }
// checks to see if $_POST['find'] is actually set.
if ( array_key_exists('find',$_POST) )
{
    $searchKeyword = $_POST['find']; // Sanitize this value first !!

   // sanitize $searchKeyword here

}

// checks to see if $searchKeyword has no value, or just contains empty space
if ( empty(trim($searchKeyword)) )
{
    echo "You must enter a search term";
} 
else
{
   $sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations WHERE `Animal_Type` LIKE '%$searchKeyword%' ");

  if ($sql == FALSE)
  {
    die($sql." Error on query: ".mysqli_error($link)); 
  }

  while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    echo  $result ['Animal_Type'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result ['Latitude'];
    echo "<br> ";
    echo $result ['Longitude'];
    echo " <br>";
    echo $result ['Seen'];
    echo " <br> ";
    echo $result ['Time'];
    echo "<br> ";
    echo "<br> ";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Apologies. I've modified the code to be stricter, give that a shot.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '{'

This is the error I get again. Can't seem to find where the parenthesis is missing

Comment: Would you be able to explain what you did there pls?

Comment: by adding `if ( array_key_exists('find',$_POST) )` I've made sure that $searchKeyword is only set if 'find' is defined in the database submission. By putting the clause `if ( empty(trim($searchKeyword)) )` in I've made the code branch if $seachKeyword is empty ( that is is `undefined`, `NULL`, `0`, `''` (an empty string) or `false`). The use of trim on ($searchKeyword) removes any leading or trailing space, which means that a string `' '` will be transformed to `''`, which is empty. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **"%"** from either the back or the front of the $searchKeyword in the query and I guess it should do the work. 
"**%**" is used when match all or none. So if you send an empty string it will return the whole database.